# ¿Como crear encabezados en word con Apche POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo este código:

```
XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();    
XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
String imgFile = "C:\\Users\\Leath\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\usuario_1\\src\\imagenes\\encabezado.png";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
run.addBreak();
run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(500), Units.toEMU(50));
run.addBreak();
is.close();
```

Pero como pueden ver solo estoy creando un párrafo y me gustaría que a a hora de que me genere el word me genere la imagen en el encabezado, o en su defecto aprender a sobre escribir una plantilla en word

Comment: Una pregunta, siempre va ser la misma imagen?

Comment: si, siempre sera la misma imagen

Comment: Utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/94185/edit) en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si siempre vamos a tener el mismo encabezado. Te sugiero uses un **platilla** puedes hacer un documento de word donde agregues la imagen en el encabezado y todo el texto que necesites, así si en el futuro cambia el encabezado no necesitas romperte la cabeza si cambia de posición una cosa trivial

Así podemos tener este código que lee tu platilla (fíjate que es `.docx` porque hay un bug cuando se usa `.dotx`)

```
String path = "D:\\templates\\mitemplate.docx";
try {            
    //Carmagos el template
    XWPFDocument template = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

    //agregamos el nuevo contenido
    XWPFParagraph para = template.createParagraph();

    XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
    run.setText("Hola");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("nuevo.docx"));

    template.write(fos);

    fos.close();

}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Y si requerimos un cambio simplemente modificamos nuestro word y lo depositamos en la ruta que tengamos.

Comment: gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: Perdón provee así el código y no consigo que haga algo, cual es el error